# Docker on Mac... Can't access anything on local network

Tags: macos, docker, networking, osx-elcapitan

Running OSX 10.11.6 (for campatibility reasons with some other software that isn't compatible with anything higher, so upgrading OSX isn't a solution) and the highest version of Docker compatible with 10.11.6, which is 17.12.0-ce-mac55 (23011).

Before I continue, I should say I'm not too knowledgeable when it comes to networks, subnets, netmasks, gateways, etc...

From inside any of my containers, I cannot access any hosts on my local network (apart from the host machine). My network config looks like this on the host:

```
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:b6:69:51:f3
    inet6 fe80::250:b6ff:fe69:51f3%en4 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
    inet 172.25.18.19 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 172.25.19.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

and like this in a container:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:C0:A8:10:04
          inet addr:192.168.16.4  Bcast:192.168.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1683 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:2551 (2.4 KiB)
```

For example, from the host, I can telnet to an HP JetDirect box on 172.25.33.51, but not from any container. Similarly, I can get a response from our Navision server's SOAP server from the host, on 172.20.38.62, but not from any container. Same story with a few other machines on slightly different IPs.

Problem is, I need to write an integration bundle that connects to Navision.

Any ideas how I can get access to hosts on the network?

Comment: Are you able to ping 8.8.8.8 from inside the container? What is the output when you run `docker network ls`? Have you taken the time to read through the docs? https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-the-default-bridge-network

Comment: Yeah, I can ping external IPs. We have a bunch of Digital Ocean servers, and I can connect to APIs and services on them, no problem. `docker network ls` gives https://gist.github.com/theplankmeister/b32ea423a35939bf6885c9dc2cec827d
I've read the docs, and tried days' worth of things... Starting to think this just isn't possible. Docker on Mac seems to be a bit of a mutant. My workplace have banned Linux, though, so... :/

Comment: The same issue on my side: it is not possible to access the host machine network from a container